# jQuery : how to prevent animation in related div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidedown, slideup

is there any option to prevent `slideUp()` when hover its related div ?

```
$('#member1').hover(function () {
    $("#memberdetails2").hide();
    $("#memberdetails1").stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function () {
    $("#memberdetails1").stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
$('#memebr2').hover(function () {
    $("#memberdetails1").hide();
    $("#memberdetails2").stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function () {
    $("#memberdetails2").stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/zDYyB/

Comment: What's a related div?

Comment: edit your question to explain what a related div means in your case :)

Comment: @j08691 slideDown div is the related div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zDYyB/2/

If you want the members detail to be always visible, remove

```
$('#company').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $('.membersare').hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks you very much for you answer. I would like to fix the flicker when mouse move from **red** to **green**. if you know the solution that would be great

Comment: You will need to update your CSS as well to prevent the flickering. I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zDYyB/3/ Check the updated CSS and the updated JS line :)